# .NET Windows Forms Application Update Deployment

Tags: .net, winforms, deployment, installation, publish

We have an inner corporation Windows Forms application on .NET 4.0. Our problem is, some of the users are having troubles while updating the application because it is already installed.

The way that we publish the application is:

- Go to properties of the project
- Set new version to the application, set the update URL of the application.
- Publish the app to local.
- Deploy the app to the update URL.

By this, application always checks if a new version is deployed, and if so, it downloads and installs it.

As I said, our problem is that some of the users cannot install the application update properly and the app crashes. Then, we tell the users to uninstall the program and download the setup packege from the deployment place (Actually, as we couldn't fix the program, we had to write another application that does that!).

As it is not the same for all the users, I can't understand why this happens. One of our developers insists that this is a network related problem, but I wonder if we can set an absolute solution for that.

Why does this not work? How to fix it?

Comment: This question is likely far too open-ended for SO.  You would be better served to ask a very direct question.  A broadly worded "why does this whole process not work" is not answerable here,.

Comment: Is it possible the app is targeted for a specific platform (32/64 bit) and the users having the problem are running the other one?

Comment: Please try doing this one. and check in your pre-prod environment from different users. Before publishing change the GUID of the application.Right click  on the solution properties on the application > Assembly Information Change the GUID before publishing.
for generating the GUID from visual studiofollowing steps can be perfomed 
Tools > create GUID > select Define GUID > click New GUID > click on copy  > paste on to any note pad and take the created GUID from there. If this worked for you please let me know i will add this as answer. Thanks

Comment: @kishoreVM Can you explain in which way this would help?

Comment: This looks like regular application users don't have sufficient permissions to download and install the application. I suppose the installer/updated part of the software will need to have elevated permissions to download/install application on local machine.

Comment: After manually uninstalling, downloading and re-installing, does the program still crash on the end users' computers that experienced the update failure?

Comment: I think, By Changing GUID of the application assembly.click once will see it as an update ( forced Update ).

Answer (score 1):

There is a another way for your problem.
You should maintain version and update table user vise at database side.
when user log in it will check the version on server and also current version if its differ.
just a batch file with commands run for updation of particular executable.

Comment: We're not having trouble while trying to detect if the app is up to date or not, but while updating it. I didn't get how this will help.

Comment: Ya.. exactly got your point but batch file can handle.. You may detect scenario of problem and maintain solution conditions in batch file.

Answer (score 1):

You must find the details why the particular installation has failed from the log of ClickOnce installations. It is by default in "Temporary internet folder".  See [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4276713/2224701) or [article here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/srib/archive/2007/11/04/clickonce-troubleshooting.aspx). You must definitely see the cause in the log file to troubleshoot it.

Usually it is OK to uninstall the application from Control panel and then install anew from the same URL or UNC path. Also it could be necessary to clear ClickOnce application cache `%userprofile%\Local Settings\Apps\2.0`.

Click once usually works well with smaller applications, from my experience problems happen more often with bigger apps with many libraries.

I am afraid that "an absolute solution" would be not to use click once deployment method.